# Deep Copy vs creating new class object each time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm working on a code base which is facing performance issues. There I saw Class ABC which is very huge (n number of data members, LIST of members of different classes) and have number of methods to perform operation for any object.

Further they have another Class XYZ which is creating objects of this ABC class (at least 10-15 objects - may be they have such business case). From code, what I understood is, that they need independent objects (deep copy). So I need your help to understand whether to implement deep copy by any mean like Serialization, Mannual or by using MemberwiseClone? Or let the code in the way it is now.

Can anyone comment on performance aspect of these two approaches?

Lang: C# (VS 2013)

Comment: Have you ran a tracing profiler over the code to identify hot paths? Did you actually see these classes causing a problem? Or did you assume that because they are large they may be the issue?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm assuming that since they are large, so they would be taking time to have a new object again and again. So, I'm thinking for a short (optimize) way to do that. I don't know if Deep Copy can help.. I'm exploring.. Any idea?

Comment: I would take a different path to tackle the problem. First, make sure they are actually the problem by profiling your code. There are great profilers for C#, I've personally had great experience with dotTrace by JetBrains. After you've identified the hotpaths, start optimizing as you go, one by one. Don't fall into gut feelings, they can often hindsight you from the real problem.